# Changing the name of the iOS Application during development

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, build-process

I have two targets in my Project.
BINS LIVE and BINS DEMO

I've set "Bundle display name" and "Bundle name" inside Bins Demo-Info.plist to "Bins Demo"

Also I set "Product name" in Packaging section of the Build Settings to "Bins Demo"

In BINS LIVE target I made similar changed but instead "Bins Demo" I have set only "Bins".

What I tried so far:

1. Restart app from xCode. The name on the iOS device remain "BINS"
2. Restart xCode, clear the build directory. The name stays "BINS" on iOS device.
3. I created special entry with APP id with name (Bins Demo), separate bundle identifier and provisioning. Set new provisioning profile in xCode and rebuild. Still the same name "BINS".

The funny thing is that project is named Bins but not BINS.

How can I change name of the application under app icon in iOS device? I'm working on xCode 7 and iPhone 6 with iOS 9 onboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting the simulator, with the simulator open click on:

**Simulator** --> Reset Content and Settings..

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with localization. I removed InfoPlist.strings file and now changes in targets seems to work. I spend 3 hours on that shit :)